# api-pagination gem configuration error in Rails 5 when deployed to heroku

Tags: heroku, pagination, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I am using the `api-pagination` gem and deploying to heroku in a rails 5 app. My configuration is ok in development but fails in production. Here is the config file:

`config/initializers/api_pagination.rb`

```
ApiPagination.configure do |config|
  # If you have both gems included, you can choose a paginator.
  config.paginator = :will_paginate

  # By default, this is set to 'Total'
  config.total_header = 'X-Total'

  # By default, this is set to 'Per-Page'
  #config.per_page_header = 'X-Per-Page'

  # Optional: set this to add a header with the current page number.
  #config.page_header = 'X-Page'

  # Optional: what parameter should be used to set the page option
  config.page_param = :page
  # or
  config.page_param do |params|
    params[:page][:number]
  end

  # Optional: what parameter should be used to set the per page option
  config.per_page_param = :per_page
  # or
  config.per_page_param do |params|
    params[:page][:size]
  end
end
```

Here is the error from the heroku logs:

```
[INFO ] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 
[FATAL] NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
[FATAL] config/initializers/api_pagination.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The controller action is very simple right now:

```
  def index
    listings = Listing.where(active: true)
    paginate json: listings
  end
```

I am including no parameters in the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my situation, most of the configuration was unnecessary. I'm not sure why it was causing an error but the defaults for my case are fine, except that I use `will_paginate`. This is my config file and it works:

```
ApiPagination.configure do |config|
  # If you have both gems included, you can choose a paginator.
  config.paginator = :will_paginate
end
```

If someone follows up with a solution that addresses the error, I will accept it. It might be useful for someone else that requires more of the non-default settings.